# JMS on Websphere MQ and backout queue

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean, weblogic12c

I have MQ as an external JMS server on my Weblogic server. The thing is that I need to rollback the message and retry until backout threshold is reached. Then I need to move the message to backout queue.

The MessageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly() method takes care of that just fine. The problem, however, is with the message on the backout queue - it is uncommited.

Moreover, the messages are being taken from backout queue and processed again as soon as new message appears on the main queue.

This suggest me that there is something teribly wrong with my approach. I cannot, however, change the fact, that I have to retry the onMessage() with the same message a couple of times and send it to backout queue is backout threshold was reached.

```
@MessageDriven( name="MQListener", mappedName = "jms.mq.SOME.QUEUE.NAME",
        activationConfig = 
        { 
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms.mq.SOME.QUEUE.NAME"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryJndiName", propertyValue = "jms.mq.MQ"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true")
        }) 
public class MQListener implements MessageListener {
    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext context;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        String messageContent="";

        try {
            messageId = message.getJMSMessageID();
            if (message != null) {
                messageContent = ((TextMessage)message).getText();
                if(!doSomething(messageContent)){
                    // doSomething fails, I need to rollback the message and try again:
                    context.setRollbackOnly();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    }

    private boolean doSomething(String messageContent){
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a tyro in EJB. But from what I can see in your code snippet, I think you are missing initialization of `MessageDrivenContext`. I think you will have to do either

```
context = getMessageDrivenContext(); 
context.setRollbackOnly();
```

or

```
getMessageDrivenContext().setRollbackOnly();
```

Comment: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MessageDrivenEJBContextImpl is injected here. But I'll follow this lead, maybe wrong resources are being injected. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No luck. The problem is that after the delivery count exceeds, the message is moved to the backout queue and stays there uncommitted. Therefore, the problem still exists.

Comment: Did you solve it? 

It is responsibility of jms client (essentially your WMQ rar archive) to transfer message to backout queue. In JEE this should happen automatically. Try raising exception in listener when 'doSomething' returns false. Check your AS/Transaction Manager settings.